# Keep both dataframes' own values only replace at intersection in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have the following two data-frames and I want to merge them using `merge` function.

```
> x <- data.frame(id=c("a", "b", "c"), type=c("good", "ok", "not-ok"))
> y <- data.frame(id=c("b", "d"), type=c("ok", "good"), kind=c("A", "B"))
> merge(x, y, by.x="id", by.y="id", all=TRUE)
  id type.x type.y kind
1  a   good   <NA> <NA>
2  b     ok     ok    A
3  c not-ok   <NA> <NA>
4  d   <NA>   good    B
```

What I want to get is

```
  id   type    kind
1  a   good    <NA>
2  b     ok       A
3  c not-ok    <NA>
4  d   good       B
```

Is there a nice way to do this in R, please? Thanks.

Comment: what is wrong with your solution? What do you mean by nice?

Comment: Try `merge(x, y, all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

In Base R:

```
merge(x, y, all = TRUE)
```

With `tidyverse`:

First, an addition when you are creating your data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c("a", "b", "c"), type=c("good", "ok", "not-ok"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

y <- data.frame(id=c("b", "d"), type=c("ok", "good"), kind=c("A", "B"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to prevent Warnings in the next step:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- full_join(x,y)
```

Edited based on @markus' comments.

Answer (score 1):

Easy!

```
library(dplyr)

x %>% full_join(y, by  = c("id", "type"))

  id   type    kind
1  a   good    <NA>
2  b     ok       A
3  c not-ok    <NA>
4  d   good       B
```